# Conditional MYSQL select, depending on other table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables;

1. `store_referrals` table, it has an `orderid` column, and `referer` column.
2. `store_orders` table, it has a `time` column and `orderid` column.

I want to select the `referer` from `store_referrals`, only if the `time` from `store_orders` is within the `last 60 days`.

Of course the corresponding rows from `store_orders` will be linked by the common `orderid` for the two tables.

Any clue ?

Comment: you can put whatever conditions you want in the `join`, e.g. `join foo on (foo.x = bar.y) AND (....)`, but what you want can be done with a simple `where joinedtable.time > (now() - interval 60 day)`

Answer (score 2):

TRY WITH THIS

```
SELECT referer FROM store_referrals sr JOIN store_orders so ON sr.orderid=so.orderid WHERE (DATEDIFF(NOW(),DATE(so.time)))<60;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateDiff`:

```
select a.referer
from store_referrals a
join store_orders b on a.orderid = b.orderid
where datediff(now() - b.time) < 60;
```

> DATEDIFF() returns expr1 – expr2 expressed as a value in days from one
>   date to the other. expr1 and expr2 are date or date-and-time
>   expressions. Only the date parts of the values are used in the
>   calculation